# Selecting one row from a group in SQL with multiple selectors

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping, mysql-5.6

*(This question is specific to MySQL 5.6, which does not include CTEs)*

Let's say I have a table like this (actual table is made from a subquery with several joins and is a fair bit more complex):

```
ID  NAME    POWER    ACCESS_LEVEL  DEPTH
1   Odin    poetry   1             0
1   Isis    song     2             1
2   Enki    water    1             0
2   Zeus    storms   2             2
2   Thor    hammer   2             3
```

I want to first group them up by `ID` (it's actually a double grouping by `PRINCIPAL_TYPE, PRINCIPAL_ID` if that matters), then select one row from each group, preferring the row with the highest `ACCESS_LEVEL`, and among rows with the same access, choosing the one with the lowest depth. No two rows will have the same `(ID, DEPTH)` so we don't need to worry beyond that point.

For example with the above table, we select:

```
ID  NAME    POWER    ACCESS_LEVEL  DEPTH
1   Isis    song     2             1
2   Zeus    storms   2             2
```

The groups are (Odin, Isis) and (Enki, Thor, Zeus). In the first group, we prefer Odin over Isis because Odin has a higher `ACCESS_LEVEL`. In the second group, we take Zeus because Zeus and Thor have higher `ACCESS_LEVEL`s than Enki, and between those two, Zeus has the lower depth.

Worst case Ontario, I can do it at the application level, but doing it at the database level allows for using `LIMIT` and `SORT BY` to do paging, instead of fetching the whole result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method that uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where (access_level, depth) = (select access_level, depth
                               from t t2
                               where t2.id = t.id
                               order by access_level desc, depth asc
                               limit 1
                              );
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work.

```
select *
from your_table t1
where (t1.access_level, t1.depth) = (
   select t2.access_level, min(t2.depth)
   from your_table t2
   where (t2.access_level, t2.id) = (
      select max(t3.access_level), t3.id
      from your_table t3
      where t3.id = t1.id
   )
)
```

However, I feel that Gordon's solution will probably lead to a better query plan.

Answer (score 1):

Could be you need  some  grouped  table based on subquery

```
  select * 
  my_table m2
  inner join (
  select id, t.level, min(depth) depth 
  from my_table m
  inner join  (
   select id, max(ACCESS_LEVEL)  level 
   from  my_table
   group by id ) t on t.id= m.id and t.level = m.access_level
  group by id level ) t2 on t2.id = m2.id 
        and t2.depth = m2.depth and t2.level = m2.access_level
```